# Username not stored in session across PHP

Tags: php, authentication, passwords

So I am having a problem storing the username typed into my site and keeping myself logged into the site. I can log in (I see this because of the "You have been logged in" message. but the second I click the link to go to the members.php page it returns the echo "You are not logged in.".
Why isn't the $username value being added to the SESSION?

Here are 4 of my codes. I have a fifth one aswell with all my MySQL information, which I dont wish to share, however, my username is confirmed via the MySQL since I receive the first login validation. YES, I followed a tutorial on YouTube.

index.php

```
<html>

    <form action='login.php' method='POST'>
    Username: <input type='username' name='username'><br>
    Password: <input type='password' name='password'><br>
    <input type='submit' name='button' value='Login'>
    </form>

 </html>
```

login.php

```
<?php

    session_start();

    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $username = $_POST['username'];

    include ("connect.php");

if ($username && $password)
{
    // info is provided
    $queryget = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM login WHERE username='$username' AND password ='$password' ");
    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($queryget);
    if ($numrows != 0)
    {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;

        echo "You have been logged in. <a href='members.php'>Go to the members page</a>";
    }
    else echo "This password is wrong";
    include ("index.php");

}
else
{
    echo "Wrong password, try again!";
    include ("index.php");
}

?>
```

members.php

```
<?php

session_start();
$username = $_SESSION['username'];

if ($username)
    {
    echo "Welcome $username | <a href='logout.php>Logout</a>'";
    }
else
    {
    echo "You are not logged in.";
    include ("index.php");

    }

?>
```

logout.php

```
<?php

session_start();
$username = $_SESSION['username'];

session_destroy();

echo "You have been logged out.";

?>
```

Comment: One day, someone will try to log in as `'; DROP TABLE login; --` and you'll be crying out loud.

Comment: Isn't that possible with anything though? Thought you had to get into the server's Mysql to get around it...

Comment: @Denis PHP’s MySQL extension does not allow multiple statements. But you should [fix that SQL injection vulnerability](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/53114), FriedBitz. Entering the password `' OR '1'='1` would bypass the authentication.

Comment: I shall take a look on it, but at the moment I dont have anything to hide, just learning the basics of MySQL and PHP communication :) Thanks for the tip!

Comment: aside from the horrible security flaws and the inefficient mysql query, it looks like it should work.
have you tried a simpler test? `test1.php` where you set a session var, `test2.php` where you read it?

Comment: Well that is basically what is happening between the index, login and the members page... they can connect, but it doesn't result in the correct statement... it gives me the "else" statement insted of the "if" statement even if the username is set to $username.

Comment: What happens when you do a `var_dump($_SESSION);` on the `members.php` page? Can you add the output of the `var_dump()` to your question?

Comment: You mean before the if statement or inside of it?

Comment: Add the `var_dump($_SESSION); exit;` php directly after `session_start();`

Comment: and do you want me to add the var_dump() within the if statement then or? just delete the $username = $_SESSION['username']; part?

Comment: no its ok, it only needs to be after the `session_start()` function, like this:   `session_start();  var_dump($_SESSION); exit; $username = $_SESSION['username'];`, but it has to be in `members.php`

Comment: It gave me: array(0) { }

Comment: @FriedBitz I have added an answer, If you could look over it, look especially at the `mysql_query() or die()` line, and also the `if($numrows>0)` line.

Comment: Okai, so I searched around a bit, and apparently this function might still not be possible, could it be it? $queryget = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM login WHERE username='$username' AND password ='$password' ") or die(mysql_error());
    if(!$queryget){ echo 'An error occured: ' . mysql_error(); exit; }

    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($queryget);

Answer (score 0):

After looking at your code, there may be an error in your SQL query. 
You are doing the following to check for users:

```
if($numrows!=0)...
```

However, if `mysql_query` or `mysql_num_rows` returns false (if there was an error), then this would also authenticate the user.

Try the following code below in `login.php` and see what happens.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
session_start();

include ("connect.php");

$password = $_POST['password'];
$username = $_POST['username'];

$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);

if ($username!='' && $password!='')
{
    // info is provided
    $queryget = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM login WHERE username='$username' AND password ='$password' ") or die(mysql_error());
    if(!$queryget){ echo 'An error occured: ' . mysql_error(); exit; }

    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($queryget);

    if ($numrows > 0)
    {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;

        echo "You have been logged in. <a href='members.php'>Go to the members page</a>";
        exit;
    } else {
        echo "The username or password is wrong";
       include ("index.php");
       exit;
    }
} else if($username=='') {
    echo "You need to specify a username, try again!";
    include ("index.php");
    exit;
} else if($password=='') { 
    echo "You need to specify a password, try again!";
    include("index.php");
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Also, I'd advise you to move away from `mysql_*` functions, its depreciated, perhaps start using `mysqli` or `PDO`. At the very least, escape your mysql input :)

Comment: This made my login stop working... I dont even get the You have been logged in message...

Comment: In this case, you may have a mysql error. I have updated my answer, if you could run this one instead, hopefully it should output the error message

Comment: @FriedBitz, i've updated the code again, (appologies for all the updates, I'm trying to narrow down exactly what the error is), if you could try the new code?

Comment: haha, dont worry, just want to figure this problem out. Got the message: You need to specify a username, try again!

Comment: Ah, misread your last comment! Ok, if you do a `var_dump($_POST); exit;` after `session_start()` in my answer, and then post the results?

Comment: Here it is, pathethic password, I know, haha :P array(3) { ["username"]=> string(9) "FriedBitz" ["password"]=> string(8) "Password" ["button"]=> string(5) "Login" }

Comment: In my answer (sorry!), i've updated it again. I've moved the `include('connect.php');` to directly below the `session_start()` function. Could you try this please?

Comment: Okai, I could get logged in again now, but when I hit the link it says You are not logged in again....

Comment: Ok, at least the login script is working now :) On the `members.php` page again, could you do a `var_dump($_SESSION); exit;` directly below the `session_start()` function and comment the results? I'm now thinking there may be a problem saving the data to the session (maybe due to permissions?)

Comment: Yeah, think it wont save for some reason... Got array(0) { }

Comment: Its either going to be an issue with permissions, saving the data to the `tmp` folder, or you have `php errors` hidden, and theres output to the browser before using sessions. I'll update my answer to hopefully display any errors to the screen.

Comment: Okai, let me know when its updated, I have been working on this problem for about 5 hours straight and its 01:45 so, I need a break, I will notify you when I wake up again. Thanks so far!

Comment: I've updated the answer, I'm on most days so i'll pick it up again later!

Comment: Hey, so do the problem is remembering the session after going away from the login.php..... What problems can cause this? I haven't checked your code yet, but is the problem really in login.php?

Answer (score -1):

```
login.php:

<?php
 session_start();

    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $username = $_POST['username'];

    include ("connect.php");

if ($username && $password)
{
    // info is provided
    $queryget = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM login WHERE username='$username' AND password ='$password' ");
    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($queryget);
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($queryget);
    if ($numrows != 0)
    {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
        $_SESSION['logged']   = 1;

        echo "You have been logged in. <a href='members.php'>Go to the members page</a>";
    }
    else 
    {
    $_SESSION['logged']   = 0;
    echo "This password is wrong";
    include ("index.php");}

}
else
{
    echo "Wrong password, try again!";
    include ("index.php");
}

?>

member.php:
<?php 
session_start();
if($_SESSION['logged'])
{

 echo "Welcome $_SESSION['username'] | <a href='logout.php>Logout</a>'";
}
```

else
    {
    echo "You are not logged in.";
    include ("index.php");

```
}
?>
```

Comment: This made the whole thing just give me a error when I hit the link from the login....

Comment: try: if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){}

Comment: nope, still can't give me the if statement: echo "Welcome $username | <a href='logout.php>Logout</a>'";

Comment: are sure that you are logged in?

Comment: It returns the echo in the login.php saying "You have been logged in" which validates that it has been checked with my MySQL server. If it saves is another problem it seemes...

Comment: ok.you can edit login.php.add this stmt:$row=mysql_fetch_array($queryget);and in if condition edit:$_session['username']=$row['username'];

Comment: Where exacly do I add that? Infront of/behind what?

Comment: if ($username && $password)
{
    // info is provided
    $queryget = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM login WHERE username='$username' AND password ='$password' ") or die(mysql_error());
    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($queryget);
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($queryget);
    if ($numrows > 0)
    {
        $_session['username']=$row['username'];

        echo "You have been logged in. <a href='members.php'>Go to the members page</a>";
    } else {
        echo "This password is wrong";
       include ("index.php");
    }
}